# How Do For Loops Work In Scheme?

Tags: for-loop, scheme, racket

I'm having some difficulty understanding how for loops work in scheme. In particular this code runs but I don't know why

```
 (define (bubblesort alist)
  ;; this is straightforward
  (define (swap-pass alist)
    (if (eq? (length alist) 1)
        alist
        (let ((fst (car alist)) (scnd (cadr alist)) (rest (cddr alist)))
          (if (> fst scnd)
              (cons scnd (swap-pass (cons fst rest)))
              (cons fst (swap-pass (cons scnd rest)))))))
  ; this is mysterious--what does the 'for' in the next line do?
  (let for ((times (length alist))
            (val alist))
    (if (> times 1)
        (for (- times 1) (swap-pass val))
        (swap-pass val))))
```

I can't figure out what the `(let for ((` is supposed to do here, and the `for` expression in the second to last line is also a bit off putting--I've had the interpreter complain that `for` only takes a single argument, but here it appears to take two.

Any thoughts on what's going on here?

Answer (score 14):

That's not a for loop, that's a named `let`. What it does is create a function called `for`, then call that; the "looping" behavior is caused by recursion in the function. Calling the function `loop` is more idiomatic, btw. E.g.

```
(let loop ((times 10))
   (if (= times 0)
     (display "stopped")
     (begin (display "still looping...")
            (loop (- times 1)))))
```

gets expanded to something like

```
(letrec ((loop (lambda (times)
                 (if (= times 0)
                   (display "stopped")
                   (begin (display "still looping...")
                          (loop (- times 1)))))))
  (loop 10))
```

Comment: Many thanks, I expanded the named let as you described, and it makes much more sense to me now.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't actually using a `for` language feature but just using a variation of `let` that allows you to easily write recursive functions. See [this](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html) documentation on `let` (it's the second form on there).

What's going on is that this `let` form binds the name it's passed (in this case `for`) to a procedure with the given argument list (`times` and `val`) and calls it with the initial values. Uses of the bound name in the body are recursive calls.

Bottom line: the `for` isn't significant here. It's just a name. You could rename it to `foo` and it would still work. Racket does have actual for loops that you can read about [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html).